# Untag myself from a Facebook comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-tags, facebook-comments

Some friend (or sometimes a spam application) has tagged me (and possibly others) within a comment on a random post on another friend's timeline.

[image]

**Problem**: It is annoying to be associated with that post that I know nothing about. As the post is public, all of my friends and half of the country see it. I have a friend who gets tagged a lot in public posts and as a result she (involuntarily) pollutes my news feed with insensitive content.

**Question**: How to remove the tag from that comment?

**Note**: I don't want to untag myself from a picture or post, but from a comment.

There seems to be no control to remove the tag, nor on the post itself nor on the comment nor on my name. The three dots on the right with the tooltip "Hide or report this" only has these options:

[image: Hide comment - Give feedback or report this comment]

None of these two options sound like they will actually untag me.

Comment: Could you use colored blocks to anonymize your image? The peppers are distracting and making it hard to see the actual content.

Comment: @ale: I used a different image in which I believe the peppers looks less distracting. Simple blocks would make it hard to understand what is part of the screenshot and what has been redacted.

Answer (score 5):

There is no option to untag yourself from a comment. So many people have raised this issue but Facebook still has not included this feature.

See [*Arie L* 's answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=682019425146211) (from Facebook Help Team) on the same question.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a way to untag yourself:

1) Go to your Activity Log
2) Find this line:

[image: mentioned you in a comment]

3) Press the "pen" icon with a "Edit" tooltip
4) Click "Report/Remove tag".
5) This dialog appears:

[image: Help us understand what's happening]

6) If a friend tagged you thiking it was a good idea, select "It's annoying or not interesting". If an app tagged you automatically, select "It 's spam".
7) Another dialog appears:

[image: What you can do]

8) Click "Remove tag".
9) Congratulations, you are now untagged!

[image]

Comment: +1 but unfortunately I can't figure out how to untag a post where someone accidentally tagged my business page. https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1688341598130572?id=1912903575666924 seems outdated.

Answer (score 0):

For the past month (March 2021), this method of untagging (report / it's annoying / remove tag) no longer works. When you get to the report bit, you have to decide whether it's harassment, false data etc. etc., but no option at all for simply 'annoying - remove tag'.

The comment itself is not necessarily annoying what the person wrote, but what is annoying is being tagged or mentioned in comments all over Facebook and being unable to remove them.  People using mobile phones don't even realize they are tagging you every time they click 'reply' either.

I can't ask people individually to remove tags because (a) they don't know they're doing it and (b) there are too many!

I delete all my comments, posts, likes etc. every few weeks but sadly most people never clean up their Facebook.